# Magento 2, getting an error: "Schema is not configured for mutations." while call mutation

Tags: php, magento, graphql, magento2

I have following mutation in graphql (creating new customer - something like user registration):

```
mutation {
  createCustomer(
    input: {
      firstname: "Bob"
      lastname: "Loblaw"
      email: "bobloblaw@example.com"
      password: "b0bl0bl@w"
      is_subscribed: true
    }
  ) {
    customer {
      firstname
      lastname
      email
      is_subscribed
    }
  }
}
```

It's copy and paste from Magento 2.4 documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/create-customer.html

When i'm trying to make **other mutation call**, i am getting the same error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Schema is not configured for mutations.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 1
        }
      ],
      "stack": [
        "GraphQLError: Schema is not configured for mutations.",
        "    at getOperationRootType (/home/marcin/projects/a24store/frontend/node_modules/graphql/utilities/getOperationRootType.js:28:13)",
        "    at executeOperation (/home/marcin/projects/a24store/frontend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:210:61)",
        "    at executeImpl (/home/marcin/projects/a24store/frontend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:104:14)",
        "    at execute (/home/marcin/projects/a24store/frontend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:64:35)",
        "    at /home/marcin/projects/a24store/frontend/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js:152:16",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {}
}
```

**My Magento 2 setup is correct, because other queries like query for getting products, categories etc. is working and give my correct response.**
I'm using clean install of Magento 2.4 version.

Magento docs don't even mention about change something in backend code. But i found something like this: https://www.mobelop.com/blog/magento2-graphql-tips-and-tricks/. There is section called: "Enabling Mutations in Magento GraphQL".

So i think i should extend or change graphql schema in some of modules. But i don't know which and where.

Comment: queries are read only ... public data... mutations probably has to be configured, user authorized and some ACL applied ... run/compare with some ready/preconfigured config (docker) ... post an issue on github?

Comment: I know that mutations has to be configured, but i don't know which and where. Magento docs don't even mention about something like that. I reported also on github: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-magento/issues/157